Dynamic Validation Rules in one struct for multiple HTTP Requests in GO
I'm working on a REST API in Go that requires handling multiple request types with different sets of required fields. Specifically, each request to my API has a different request body schema, with different required fields depending on the endpoint.
For example, I have two POST requests:

In the first request, the fields ID, UserName, and Active are required.
In the second request, only the fields ID and UserName are required.

Currently, my solution involves creating a separate struct for each request type and using the go-playground/validator library to validate these structs. Here is an example of what I mean:
import (
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
)

// Struct for request type 1
type RequestType1 struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" validate:"required"`
    UserName   string `json:"userName" validate:"required"`
    Active     bool   `json:"active" validate:"required"`
}

// Struct for request type 2
type RequestType2 struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" validate:"required"`
    UserName   string `json:"userName" validate:"required"`
    Active     bool   `json:"active"`
}

is there a solution to define one struct to use it differently in the Requests body in Go?

You didn't ask a question.

How can a bool be required?  If the value is not present in the request you'll get the zero value for bool ie false.  How would you distinguish between an active=false and active not being present in the request?

Given your example, you could simply create a base request type with only the ID and user name, and embed them into the two types you have, or you could just embed the second type into the first, and override (re-define alongside) the Active field with the required tag, but really, this feels like an X-Y problem if I'm honest

It could be tedious but I think it is better to have these two structs separated, If you use a base struct with common fields like Id and UserName and then you create structs composed with that one you will have dependencies that may do not correspond to the logic of your application. Anyways If you want that logic you can check this https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/go/composition.

I think you can create a embed struct:
import (
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
)

type Request struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" validate:"required"`
    UserName   string `json:"userName" validate:"required"`
    Active     bool   `json:"active"`
}

// Struct for request type 1
type RequestType1 struct {
    Request
}

// Struct for request type 2
type RequestType2 struct {
    Request
}

